# Apache camel - Omit xml declaration doesnt seem to be working

Tags: xml, xslt, apache-camel

I have an XSLT "xml_response_extractor.xslt" to transform an incoming SOAP msg to a XML with the following lines

```
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"   />
 <xsl:template match="/">
   <xsl:value-of select="/s:Envelope/s:Body/o:Response/o:Result" disable-output-escaping="yes" />  
 </xsl:template>
```

Then i call this xslt in my Camel route as

```
<to uri="xslt:classpath:///schema/xml_response_extractor.xslt" />
```

The transformed xml still has the declaration as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

How can I remove this?

Comment: Did you try to add the `method` attribute? If not, try `<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>`. There won't be any declaration, if you would define `text` as your output method.

Comment: method = "xml" did not work as well

Comment: Is there any other XML operation after the transformation? The declaration could be re-inserted after the transformation if there are any other XML tasks.

Comment: You are sure the declaration doesn't exist in your xslt file? At the top?